# Изображение и csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, pyqt5, csv

В общем нужно сохранить картинку в ячейку в файл формата csv.

Догадываюсь, что дело в кодировках, но не могу понять синтаксис.

Помещаю картинку в label:

```
label_3.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.pixmap))
```

Потом я ее помещаю в буфер:

```
buffer = QtCore.QBuffer()

pixmap.save(buffer, 'jpg')

stamp_data = buffer.data().Base64Encoding
```

Eсли с методом Base64Encoding, то записывается 0 в ячейку,
если без него, - то куча символов (я так понимаю картинка в кодировке).

Запись делаю в файл вот так:

```
with open("file_name.csv", "a", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
        for row in spisok_znachenii:
            writer.writerow(row)
            print(row)
```

Когда открываю записанный файл, то либо 0, либо куча символов, но нужна картинка.

В целом и общем объясните, как вообще можно положить картинку в ячейку csv или xls.

Comment: `Base64Encoding` - это не метод, а флаг https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#Base64Option-enum

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помещение картинки в буфер:

```
pixmap = QPixmap('<исходное изображение>')
buffer = QBuffer()
pixmap.save(buffer, 'jpg')

# toBase64()
stamp_data = buffer.data().toBase64()
```

Запись в csv-файл

```
file = QFile("<filename>.csv")
if file.open(QFile.WriteOnly)):
    csv = QTextStream(&file)
    csv << stamp_data
file.close()
```

Чтение из csv:

```
file = QFile("<filename>.csv")
if file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)):
    stream = QTextStream(file)
    image_data_from_csv = stream.readLine()

    pixData = QByteArray.fromBase64(image_data_from_csv)
    pixmap = QPixmap()
    pixmap.loadFromData(pixData)

    # pixmap.save('<результирующая картинка>') 
    # должна быть такой же как исходная картинка 
file.close()
```

Comment: Вот запись в ячейку происходит ...b'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD//gA+Q1... и т.д. А мне необходимо видеть картинку в ячейке...

Comment: @Артем Это и есть ваша картинка в текстовом виде формата csv-файла

Comment: ай андерстенд, бат как мне загрузить именно картинку? я уже и pillow пробовал прикрутить, никак(((

Comment: @Артем открываете ваш файл csv-файл, получаете из него данные картинки помещаете их в буфер, а из буфера в объект изображения - все расписано в ответе

Comment: @Артем в csv файл никак - это текстовый файл. Что для вас графический вид? Любой файл, включая графический имеет исходные данные. Приложения могут эти данные читать и, если распознали, например, как изображение, то отображать на экране. Сами файлы - это не приложения - это исходные данные.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения, Александр. Теперь доперло))

Comment: Если приложение распознает в данных картинку, то оно прочтет и отобразит данные как картинка. Вы какое приложение имеете в виду - иксель? Надо посмотреть как записать данные в csv, чтобы excel распознал их как картинку, думаю есть какой-то спец ключ, или флаг, если эксель не умеет распознавать их автоматом